# What Will Make Me Buy the D800 over DF if the former is cheaper?

Tags: nikon, full-frame

I just looked at my local camera shop brochure today and I just saw that the D800 body only sells for 2300USD and the DF body only sells for 2500USD. This will be my first FX purchase so I have to get a lot of opinions. Is it worth shelling out 200USD more considering these differences:

http://snapsort.com/compare/Nikon-D800-vs-Nikon-DF

but I would like to get "on the field" opinions from professionals and amateurs here who have used or owned both.

Sidenote: I had bad experience with Nikon D7000 shutter problems, and since that camera is about to die on me anyway, and I want an FX body so bad, I decided to search for a better Nikon FX alternative.

Comment: This seems a two part question: 1) what are the differences between the cameras, which you could research yourself (but Itai has summarized nicely)  I doubt many people here have any field experience with the very new DF. And 2) how those differences matter to you, and whether those differences justify the price difference.  Not really a question we can answer for you.

Comment: The Df apparently uses the sensor from the D4, so you can also look up D800 vs. D4 comparisons to help with your decision.

Comment: DF/D800: No video/video.| DF has best low light performance of any 35mm camera ever sold. Unlike the D600/D800 the actual sensor noise per pixel is lower than for a D700. BUT many other factors too.

Answer (score 6):

**These are very different cameras.** The D800 is very high resolution camera which is ideal for making very large prints The Df is an ultra-sensitive camera with extremely good low-light performance.

For landscape, architecture or any other type of photography which easily allows you to use low ISO, a D800 will deliver higher image-quality and the potential for much larger prints or tighter crops.

For action or sports photography, the Df has a number of advantages. Its high-sensitivity allows it to shoot in lower-light and its continuous drive is notably faster, increasing you changes of capturing action at its peak.